# CakePHP - Letting the User Select the Layout

Tags: cakephp

Im working on a CakePHP application that will display a DVD collection.  I would like to include a Dropdpwn Menu where the user can select their on view/colour scheme.  Nothing fancy, it just needs to either change the layout file for the CSS file.  Either will work.

Any tips?  Can't seem to figure it out.

Regards,
Jon

Comment: Assuming that you already know HTML and CSS check some documentation e.g. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html to learn how views works. Once you're familliar with it that, editing your layout should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Themes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html) to switch either layout, css, or both.

In your AppController.php add:

```
$this->theme = 'Fancy';
```

This will look for your default layout in `App/View/Themed/Fancy/default.ctp`. You choose what you want to customize with a theme. If you don't have a special layout file for the Fancy theme, CakePHP will default to `App/View/Layouts/default.ctp`. Likewise, you can choose to provide a special stylesheet in your theme which would go in `App/View/Themed/Fancy/webroot/css/default.css` and if not CakePHP would use `App/View/webroot/css/default.css`.

You can set the user's theme selection to a [Cookie](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html) so it's remembered.

You didn't say which version of CakePHP you're using, but the solution will be similar in either 2.x or 3. The above links are to the 2.x Cookbook.

Comment: I think the themes are more than I really need.  All i really need to happen is from the below form:`<?php 
            echo $this->Form->create(); 
            
            echo $this->Form->input('layout', array(
                'options' => array(
                    'default' => 'Default', 
                    'fancy' => 'Fancy',
                    'plain' => 'Plain'
                    )
                ));
            
            echo $this->Form->end('Change Layout');
           
        ?>`       grab the choice and add an if statement to check which CSS file to use

Comment: I still think Themes are the best solution here because you can choose at any time how much you want to customize and the rest will default to your non-themed files. I added more info to the answer. It also means keeping any logic out of your view files.